# SQL Server Remote Update alternatives

Tags: sql-server

I want to know if there are any other alternatives than using this join to do a remote update. I'm new to using linked servers and I've read that joins can perform poorly (depending on the implementation). For reference the local table is small and the remote table is big and they both have the same schema and table names.

[Update]

- Added note that the table names and schema are the same.
- Added execution plan.

**This works:**

```
UPDATE remoteTable
SET remoteTable.[Data] = mylocalTable.[Data]
FROM [RemoteServer].[MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable] remoteTable
INNER JOIN [dbo].[MyTable] myLocalTable ON (remoteTable.[Id] = myLocalTable.[Id])
```

[image: Execution plan]

**These don't work.** I've tried the following queries and got these errors.

```
UPDATE [RemoteServer].[MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable]
SET [Data] = [dbo].[MyTable].[Data]
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE [Id] = [dbo].[MyTable].[Id])
```

> The objects "RemoteServer.MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable" and "dbo.MyTable" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

```
UPDATE [RemoteServer].[MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable]
SET [Data] = mylocalTable.[Data]
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] myLocalTable
WHERE [Id] = myLocalTable.[Id])
```

> Ambiguous column name 'id'.

```
UPDATE [RemoteServer].[MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable]
SET [Data] = mylocalTable.[Data]
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] myLocalTable
WHERE ([RemoteServer].[MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable].[Id] = myLocalTable.[Id])
```

> The multi-part identifier "RemoteServer.MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable.Id" could not be bound.

```
MERGE [RemoteServer].[MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable] remoteTable
USING [dbo].[MyTable] localTable ON (remoteTable.[Id]=localTable.[Id])
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
         SET [Data] = localTable.[Data]
;
```

> The target of a MERGE statement cannot be a remote table, a remote view, or a view over remote tables.

Comment: "'I'm new to using linked servers and I've read that joins can perform poorly" - so, how does yours perform???

Comment: Not sure why you are keen on removing joins. It seems all you need to do is fix those rather simple syntax problems and you're good.

Comment: I fine using a join I just want to know if there is a better way to do it, or something I can compare it with.  

@usr Can you help me resolve the syntax issue? AFAIK you can only use table alias in the from clause for an update so that leaves only a join. I'm not sure how to resolve the multi-part identifier issue.

Comment: @user3811205 I offered an answer three hours ago. Have you tried that?

Comment: @user3811205 since you are ignoring the other answer I am not inclined to post another one.

Answer (score 0):

Does this run?

```
UPDATE RemoteServer.MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable
SET Data = (
    SELECT Data
    FROM myLocalTable lt
    WHERE lt.Id = MyTable.Id
)
```

I'm not sure if your table names are identical between the two servers. Make sure to alias the one inside the query and refer to the updating table in the correlation without the four-part name.

Comment: The table names are identical. Your query runs, however it updates every row in the remote table.

Comment: You could add `coalesce` with the old value or `where exists` to prevent too many rows being updated. You didn't say much about the relationship between the tables in the question though.

Comment: Yeah I guess I left out some details. I can get this query to work however if I had to update multiple columns on the remote server I think it wouldn't perform as well a join. I think I'll close this question and try to get a better understanding of how the remote update actually works. Thanks for you help.

Comment: The problem with remote queries is that the data doesn't exist in one place so it might be sending it across to the other side to accomplish the join.